# Shortcuts for conditional statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I do have the following variable:

```
var text = getValue();
```

`getValue()` - can be empty, thus text === undefined, can be === "Example" but also can be === "Hello World.

I want to check two things: 1. if text !== undefined AND if text === "Hello World"

Method for achieving it:

```
if(text !== undefined && text === "Hello World")
```

**Issue**: The text variable is typed in twice for two comparisions.

**Question**: How to check two things(undefined, Hello World) but using text once?

**EDIT**: I did a mistake with the example, check the new variable text; Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a condition for `text === undefined`?

Comment: `text !== undefined && text === "Hello World"` collapse to the same condition `text === "Hello World"`. By definition if the variable is equal to `"Hello world"` then it's not `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

```js
text === "Hello World"
```

implies that it is not `undefined`, so it is the only condition needed.

```js
if (text === "Hello World") { ...
```

---

**Additional info**

To check if a string has content, you can check:

```js
if (text) { ...
```

It means the same as:

```js
if (text !== undefined && text !== null && text !== '') { ...
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your Answer! 1. I do have a situation in which a variable will be conditionally initialized with a value, thereby checking if the variable is definied or not, is absolutely needed. 2. In order to do certain things the Value of the variable should be "Hello World". This is why both checks are needed.

Comment: yeah but but the string being hello world implies its not undefined because an undefined string cannot be hello world. Therefor the check is not needed.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake should have told

Comment: @Incognito could you please _accept the answer_ so the question appears as solved? Thanks. For further information about it, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Answer (score -2):

Above answer works, but for more nested property check, use Optional chaining